# network error: Connection timed out while SSH AWS EC2 ubuntu intance

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, amazon-web-services

Need help. I have searched a lot but not able to find answer:

**Here are the steps to indicating problem.**

1. Successfully ssh aws ubuntu instance using putty from **PC1**.
2. Stopped/rebooted aws instance.
3. Trying to shh again and getting error Network error: Connection time
   out.

**Two days after:**

1. Successfully ssh same aws ubuntu instance using same private key via
   putty from **PC2** .
2. Stopped/rebooted aws instance.
3. Trying to shh again and getting error Network error: Connection time
   out.

I am able to connect once and when I try sometime later I get connection timeout error. Please note that I have not made any changes in aws setting in between but yes I stopped and restarted the aws instance.

Comment: Are you having the same problem with both PCs when it happens and have you tried using a different public IP to see if it could be firewall related?

Comment: Yes same problem with both PC and both PC are at completely different locations . One at my office and other at my home.

Comment: Did you check your logs when you were able to connect to see if there was an indication of a problem with the SSH service?  I'm also wondering if it could be related to the way you start the SSH service when it boots up.  Of course we still can't rule out a firewall issue either even if the issue is from anywhere.

Comment: I don't think firewall can be an issue because I was able to connect from the same network same network(home) at the first time and there is no firewall at my home network . But yes it could be they way ssh service restart because I am just restarting ubuntu via EC2 console and not sure what is the status/how ssh service got restarted. Please suggest how can I dubug.

Comment: The first thing to check are the logs once you're able to get back in.

Answer (score 1):

Just a silly question: Are you using the same IP address to ssh to this instance ?

Because when you stop an instance and start it again, it gets a completely new IP address.